# Как освободить память в данном односвязном списке?

Tags: c++, указатели, список, malloc, односвязный-список

Есть такая структура:

```
struct dirlist //односвязный список, каждый элемент которого описывает файл
{
    char* name;
    time_t date; //тайм штамп
    u_int64_t size; //размер файла
    struct dirlist* next; //указатель на следующий элемент списка
};
```

В функции `struct dirlist* readdirTree(struct dirlist* dlist, const char* path)` память выделяется так:

```
//Запись информации о файле в node
dlist->name = strdup(curname);
dlist->date = st.st_mtime;
dlist->size = st.st_size;
//Выделение памяти
dlist->next = (struct dirlist*)malloc(sizeof(struct dirlist));
if (dlist->next == NULL) 
{
    cout << "Element wasn't allocated!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
dlist->next->next = NULL;
dlist = dlist->next;
```

В main'е вывожу имена файлов:

```
int main()
{
    struct dirlist list, *curr;
    readdirTree(&list, "../../..");
    for (curr = &list; curr->next; curr = curr->next) 
        printf("name: %s\n", curr->name);
    freeList(&list);
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

После освобождаю память:

```
struct dirlist* freeList(struct dirlist *dlist)
{
    struct dirlist *curr;
    for (curr = dlist; curr->next; curr = curr->next)
        free(curr);
    return dlist;
}
```

Но не получается:
[image: ScreenShot]

[*Полный исходный код*](http://goo.gl/4Gh2Np)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас неправильно организован список. Вместо указателя на первый узел вы определили локальный объект узла

```
int main()
{
    struct dirlist list, *curr;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Обычно так не делается. Либо вводится дополнительная структура, которая в себе содержит указатель на первый узел списка, либо объявляется указатель на первый узел списка как сам список.

Кроме того поля этой структуры не инициализированы. Например `list->next` не задан равным нулевому указателю.

То есть список реализован некорректно.

В вашем случае удалять узлы нужно следующим образом

```
struct dirlist * freeList( struct dirlist *dlist )
{
    struct dirlist *curr = dlist->next;

    while ( curr )
    {
        struct dirlist *tmp = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
        free( tmp->name ); 
        free( tmp );
    }

    free( dlist->name );
    dlist->next = nullptr;

    return dlist;
}
```

Вы должны были показать полностью код, как добавляются узлы в список.

Также если это действительно C++ код, то вы должны использовать операторы new и delete, а не функции malloc и free.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Под скрин-ом есть ссылка на полный исходный код